# rails accessing model attributes return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So I made an `Item` class from `ActiveRecord::Base`. I've implemented the `show` action so that I could see it from `items\id`. In `show.html.erb` I have accessed all the attributes and labeled them on the file. When I went to the web page, none of the attributes showed up, only their labels. I then went to byebug to see what went wrong. The `@item` object that was storing the attributes showed up, but when I checked all of the attributes one-by-one, they were all `nil`. Does anyone know why this is happening?

[timestamp]_create_items.rb:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :items do |t|
            t.string :name
            t.text :description
            t.decimal :price

            t.timestamps null: false
        end
    end
end
```

item.rb:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name, :description, :price
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
    validates :description, presence: true,
        length: { maximum: 1000 }
    VALID_PRICE_REGEX = /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/
    validates :price, presence: true,
        :format => { with: VALID_PRICE_REGEX },
        :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}
end
```

items_controller.rb:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
        debugger
    end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
Name: <%= @item.name %>
Description: <%= @item.description %>
Price: <% @item.price %>
```

console output:

```
(byebug) @item
#<Item id: 1, name: "Ruby Gem", description: "A real Ruby Gem, the stone, not the software.", price: #<BigDecimal:ce58380,'0.1337E4',9(18)>, created_at: "2015-03-14 08:15:31", updated_at: "2015-03-14 08:15:31">
(byebug) @item.name
nil
(byebug) @item.description
nil
(byebug) @item.price
nil
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out, all I needed to do was to remove the `attr_accessor` line completely. Rails 4 uses strong parameters when it comes creating an ActiveRecord object, although in my case I'm only showing it so I do not need it.

Comment: thank you. this really should be documented in console somehow, just wasted so much time trying to figure out why everything was returning `nil` but passing validations.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you've overridden the getter methods ActiveRecord provides by using `attr_accessor`:

```
attr_accessor :name, :description, :price
```

Did you mean to use `attr_accessible` instead?

Comment: Now the page isn't loading :/
`NoMethodError (undefined method 'attr_accessible' for #<Class:0xc5968a0>):`

Comment: Sorry, I thought because you were trying to use `attr_accessor` that you meant `attr_accessible`. Yes if you're on Rails 4 you'll need to use strong parameters in the controller.